# Possibility to cancel part of a trip Lufthansa and DB

Tags: air-travel, trains, bookings, lufthansa

My wife and kid trip consists of air part (using airplane) and Deutsche Bahn part (by train). So they will arrive to Frankfurt by plane and instead of waiting for almost 5 hours for the train part I'll pick them up at airport.

Is it possible for us to cancel that second part of that trip (because connection time between "flights" is too big) and reimburse some part of that price? What should be the entry point for it - Lufthansa or the DB?

Comment: Did Lufthansa change the itinerary? If not, why is the connection time suddenly 'too big' (sic) now, although it didn't change since you booked the ticket? If you can change the ticket or cancel parts of it depends entirely on the conditions of the ticket, which we can't know.

Comment: You will definitely not get any reimbursement.

Comment: Where did you book the train component?

Comment: The whole ticket was bought on Kiss&Fly site

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the train leg of the journey is booked as part of an airline ticket (so that you have a Lufthansa flight number for the leg), canceling only the leg will be treated as a ticket change. Unless you have a fully flexible ticket, they come with high fees, so most likely you will not get any money back, but rather have to pay for it.

Lufthansa also expects you to take all flights as booked (unless you change your ticket). So it may not be a good idea to skip the train leg...at least not if this is not the last leg on the ticket. Having said this, the internet forums are full of people having skipped train legs without problems. There are often no Lufthansa conductors on the train, so they would not know whether you have been on the train. Also, if they cancel the rest of your ticket because they did not "see" you onboard the train, you can state that you have been in the on-board restaurant for the journey, so that your ticket was not checked.

But there is no *guarantee* that this will work. Also, the latter excuse constitutes lying to the airline representative.

Answer (score -1):

What train connection is that? I'm sure most connections run at least every two hours from FRA.

Is your train ticket tied to a certain train connection ("Sparpreis")? Then you are not allowed to use another connection.

If your train ticket is a "Normalpreis" you can use any connection (i.e. maybe an earlier one), when the train type is valid ("ICE", "IC/EC" or any regional train).

Comment: I think that the OP booked and AirRail leg onto a Lufthansa ticket. In this case, it is neither a "Normalpreis", nor a "Sparpreis".